# can we write 'I know the name what is his.' as complex of 'I know his name' instead of 'I know his name'

Tags: grammar

Can we write 'I know the name what is his' as complex of 'I know his name' instead of 'I know what his name is'?

Comment: No... at least not in standard English.  It is possible to use "what" to mean "that" or "which", but this usage is "now dialect or vulgar" (OED).  This usage of "what" is sometimes found in one of the more downmarket British tabloids ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_The_Sun_Wot_Won_It ).

Comment: *It is people like you what cause unrest*. Monty Python.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not idiomatic English.

"I know  his name" merely makes an assertion of fact. "I know what his name is" indicates the same fact, but implies a previous question, either explicit or implicit. "I know what is his name" means the same thing and is grammatical but sounds stilted. There are circumstances, primarily in complex written prose, where the third form is best. "I know that the name is his" is grammatical, but would be idiomatic only in very rare cases.

"I know the name what is his" is simply ungrammatical. A subordinate clause that modifies a noun must start with "which," "that," "whither," "whence," "who," "whose," or "whom." (And "whither" and "whence" are now rare, and "whom" is becoming rare.)